# Regards Band Pass Filter with AmpOp

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, cutoff-frequency

I've tried to solve this contest question regards the band pass filter (find the frequency at low-pass and high-pass filters) the picture below:

[image]

My attempt:

I consider that the first stage is 2 low-pass filter identically (R1 C1) and (R2 C_2) -  circuit RC - \$R = 5\,k\Omega\$ and \$C = 50\,nF\$

So compute the cut-off frequency: \$ f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi R_1C_1} = \frac{1}{2\pi R_2C_2} = \frac{1}{2\pi \cdot 5\cdot 10^3\cdot 25\cdot 10^{-9}} \approx 636,6 Hz \$

Seems "ok".

Continue: when I look to the second stage I can see 2 high-pass filter (C3 and R3) and (C4 and R4)

cut-off frequency: \$ f_c = \frac{1}{2\pi R_3C_3} = \frac{1}{2\pi R_4C_4}=\frac{1}{2\pi \cdot 3\cdot 10^3\cdot 10\cdot 10^{-9}} \approx 5,3 kHz \$

**The answer is letter d)**

But whats about the others resistances the circuit? and when you use the same filter in series the simple question is: the frequency response has the same value when you use only 1 low-pass filter?

I tried to simulate this circuit and figure out that the frequency cut-off ( i guess) is  \$0.79kHz\$ e \$4.18kHz\$

[SIMULATED FREQUENCY RESPONSE](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%203780112.2632456296%0Ac%20240%20160%20240%20240%200%205.0000000000000004e-8%200%0Ar%20176%20160%20240%20160%200%205000%0AO%20720%20128%20832%20128%200%0Ag%20240%20240%20240%20272%200%0A170%20176%20160%20144%20160%203%2020%201000%205%200.1%0Ar%20240%20160%20304%20160%200%205000%0Ac%20304%20160%20304%20240%200%205.0000000000000004e-8%200%0Ac%20464%20144%20528%20144%200%201e-8%200%0Ac%20528%20144%20592%20144%200%201e-8%200%0Ar%20240%2048%20304%2048%200%205000%0Ar%20304%2048%20384%2048%200%207000%0Ar%20528%20144%20528%20224%200%203000%0Ar%20592%20144%20592%20224%200%203000%0Ar%20480%2048%20592%2048%200%205000%0Ar%20592%2048%20720%2048%200%207000%0Aa%20304%20144%20464%20144%200%2015%20-15%201000000%0Aa%20592%20128%20720%20128%200%2015%20-15%201000000%0Aw%20304%20128%20304%2048%200%0Aw%20384%2048%20464%2048%202%0Aw%20464%2048%20464%20144%200%0Aw%20592%20112%20592%2048%200%0Aw%20720%2048%20720%20128%200%0Ag%20240%2048%20240%2080%200%0Ag%20304%20240%20304%20272%200%0Ag%20528%20224%20528%20272%200%0Ag%20592%20224%20592%20272%200%0Ag%20480%2048%20480%2080%200%0Ao%204%2016%200%2034%205%200.00009765625%200%20-1%20in%0Ao%202%2016%200%2034%202.5%200.00009765625%201%20-1%20out%0A)

I presumed that the correct schematic this circuit to match the same \$ f_c\$ as the question required must be such as the imagem below:

[image]

So, anyone has any advice to solve the entire circuit and provided a decent analysis to this circuit? thanks for any hints.

Comment: The question choices were in error because it did not calculate the total loss at -3dB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But whats about the others resistances the circuit?

The gain setting resistors (R5, R6, R7 and R8) do two things: -

- Set the pass-band gain
- Modify the Q of the circuit enabling a peak in the frequency response around the cut-off frequency of each stage.

> when you use the same filter in series the simple question is: the
>   frequency response has the same value when you use only 1 low-pass
>   filter?

With equal values for R1 and R2 AND C1 and C2 then the cut-off frequency is the same for a single order low pass filter. The big difference in your circuits (Sallen Key, 2nd order filters) is that any signals that are outside the pass-band are attenuated to a greater extent.

If you are asking about the change in the 3 dB point of the low-pass filter when you introduce the high-pass filter then sure, there'll be some interaction and that interaction gets worse as the two cut-off frequencies get closer. With the two cut-offs at 637 Hz and 5.3 kHz, there will be some slight interaction.

Your final circuit diagram is wrong and makes no sense. You have op-amp outputs connected to ground and that is a spoiler.